# Do you add the picture in a flutter in the link of the picture without downloading it using a certain function?

Tags: flutter, dart

When adding a picture in a flutter, is there a link? Do I have to use a certain function in addition to the links used? Are there links that prevent me from using them?

I tried using a function called a network, and then I put the links of the pictures I want, and then I turned on the program, those pictures appeared, but the problem now is that when I used it, I didn't see the error logo, and I don't know if the error is from the function or from the link of the image itself.

Comment: uhm ig, there's is ot restriction when it come using image from the web as i know. do you mind to share how you call the function image.network("") with in the link? so we can try it